# better maintainable way to combine strings from multiple options

Tags: python, python-2.7, dry

I have a scenario where the user can pass in multiple options. For each option passed in, I will get the text and then finally merge the text from multiple options and return a single string. Here is how I'm doing it for three options that I accept today. The code already looks unmaintainable and as I add more options, the logic will get worse:

```
if (len(self.options.passedin.split(",")) > 0): #multiple options were passed in
  ops = self.options.passedin.split(",")
  for op in ops:
     if (op == "option1"):
         op1_text = get_text_for_option1()
     elif (op == "option2"):
         op2_text = get_text_for_option2()
     elif (op == "option3"):
         op3_text = get_text_for_option3()

   #all three were passed in
   if ("option1" in ops and "option2" in ops and "option3" in ops):
      op1_op2 = op1_text + " " + ' '.join(w for w in op1_text.split() if w not in op2_text.split())
      op3_op1_op2 = op1_op2 + " " + ' '.join(w for w in op1_op2.split() if w not in op3_text.split())
      return op3_op1_op2
   #option1 and option2 were passed in
   elif ("option1" in ops and "option2" in ops and "option3" not in ops):
      return op1_text + " " + ' '.join(w for w in op1_text.split() if w not in op2_text.split())
   #option1 and option3 were passed in
   elif ("option1" in ops and "option3" in ops and "option2" not in ops):
      return op1_text + " " + ' '.join(w for w in op1_text.split() if w not in op3_text.split())
   #option2 and option3 were passed in
   elif ("option2" in ops and "option3" in ops and "option1" not in ops):
      return op2_text + " " + ' '.join(w for w in op2_text.split() if w not in op3_text.split())
```

The methods `get_text_for_option1` `get_text_for_option2` `get_text_for_option3` can't be combined.

Comment: Why do you need to combine them ?

Comment: I see some unnecessary/incorrect things here (`len(something) > 0` instead of `something`, `&&` instead of `and` before the edit, `'option2' in ops` and `option2 not in ops` for the last option...). I suggest taking some more time to refactor and improve whatever you can first.

Comment: If I add two more options later on then the `if/elif` logic will start getting worse and worse.

Comment: You say "passing in options". Do you mean command line arguments to the program? If so, consider using the built-in `argparse` library instead.

Comment: @Jokab I am using argparse. one of the options can be a CSV. like `python myprogra.py --someoption "option1, option2, option3"`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I've fixed the last `elif` and `&&` vs. `and`

Comment: @Anthony so you only unique characters from each option, i mean if op1 = 'abc' and op2 = 'cde' and op3 ='def', you need combined output to be 'abcdef'

Comment: @be_good_do_good in the example you provided the combined output would be `"abc cde def"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `dict` to map your option names to the appropriate function which returns the option text, join those together, then take the unique words, eg:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

options = {
    'option1': get_text_for_option1,
    'option2': get_text_for_option2,
    'option3': get_text_for_option3
}

input_text = 'option3,option1,option2'

all_text = ' '.join(options[opt]() for opt in input_text.split(','))
unique = ' '.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(all_text.split()))
```

Comment: In the dict can those strings be replaced with function calls? For example replacing `this is option one five two` with `get_text_for_option1()`

Comment: @Anthony changed to use functions

Answer (score 0):

```
if (len(self.options.passedin.split(",")) > 0): #multiple options were passed in
    ops = self.options.passedin.split(",")
    opts = {
        'op1': get_text_for_option1() if 'option1' in ops else ' '
        'op2': get_text_for_option2() if 'option2' in ops else ' '
        'op3': get_text_for_option3() if 'option3' in ops else ' '
    }
    return (opts['op1'] + opts['op2'] + opts['op3']).strip()
```